# Duvida , como resolver esse conflito?

Tags: javascript

Estou com os seguintes scripts , um para validação e outro para envio para php :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input,textarea").blur(function(){
     if($(this).val() == "")
         {
             $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid #F00", "padding": "2px"});
         }
    });
    $("#butEnviar").click(function(){
     var cont = 0;
     $("#form input,textarea").each(function(){
         if($(this).val() == "")
             {
                 $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid #F00", "padding": "2px"});
                 cont++;
             }
        });
     if(cont == 0)
         {
             $("#form").submit();
         }
    });
});
```

Esse é para validação

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#butEnviar").click(function() {
    var nome  = $("input[name=nome]").val();
    var email =  $("input[name=email]").val();
    var telefone =  $("input[name=telefone]").val();
    var assunto = $("input[name=assunto]").val();
    var msg =  $("textarea[name=msg]").val();
    $.ajax({
        "url": "enviar.php",
        "dataType": "html",
        "data": {
            "nome" : nome,
            "email":email ,
            "telefone": telefone,
            "assunto": assunto,
            "msg" : msg
        },
        "success": function(response) {
            $("div#saida").html(response);
            $("#reset").click();

        }
```

E esse para envio. Porém acho que esta dando conflito e não esta enviando os dados para `enviar.php`, o que devo fazer?

Comment: Imagino que tenhas recebido `-3` porque não é 100% claro na pergunta o que precisas. Coloquei uma resposta, espero que te ajude.

Answer (score 0):

O teu fluxo está errado pois estás a submeter via HTML e não via JavaScript/Ajax. Imagino pelo teu código Ajax que queres enviar via JavaScript e não fazer submit da form via HTML (que carrega a página de novo).

Para submeter via Ajax deves capturar o evento `submit` da form e pará-lo. Só com ele cancelado podes enviar os dados para o Ajax. Para isso muda

no código de avaliação

```
$("#butEnviar").click(function(){
```

acrescenta

```
$("#butEnviar").click(function(){
    e.preventDefault(); // para parar o submit
```

E no código onde tens o Ajax muda

```
$("#butEnviar").click(function() {
```

para o evento que vais auscultar para interceptar o evento que disparas com `$("#form").submit();`. Assim muda

```
$("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

**Podes também fazer algumas melhorias no teu código**, com menos jQuery e sem repetições assim:

Avaliação:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function uiWarning() {
        return this.classList.toggle('incomplete', this.value == '');
    }
    $("input,textarea").blur(uiWarning);
    $("#butEnviar").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cont = 0;
        var falhados = $("#form input,textarea").filter(uiWarning);
        if (falhados.length == 0) $("#form").submit();
    });
});
```

na parte de submit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        ['nome', 'email', 'telefone', 'assunto', 'msg'].forEach(function(name) {
            data[name] = document.querySelector('[name="' + name + '"]').value;
        });

        $.ajax({
            "url": "enviar.php",
            "dataType": "html",
            "data": data,
            "success": function(response) {
                $("div#saida").html(response);
                $("#reset").click();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: vou fazer o seguinte, vou deixar o link da página que estou fazendo, e dai  tu da uma olhada, eu não consegui colocar o form aqui kkk , 
No exemplo que mostrei de inicio, eu estava enviando um email via php , e dai tava certo, porém coloquei aquela validação e bugou , sei la, só sei que não está fazendo nada , talvez seja pouca coisa ou não .

newairdesign.com.br/novo/contato1.html

Comment: @RenanMoreira tens um `/` a mais na página que está a dar erro. E esqueces-te de juntar `e.preventDefault();` antes de `var data = {};`. Aliás, eu sugeri isso na resposta mas depois não coloquei no código final... Corrigi agora.

Comment: Eu modifiquei como você falou ,mas parece que ele não está enviando o email, a página php , está la no servidor , tudo certo, porque eu tinha utilizado ela em outro site, que seguia a mesma lógica, porém não cheguei a utilizar ele . 
Porque no codigo, ele enviava uma cópia do form para o usuario ,e uma cópia para mim , no caso o email do dominio, mas como teste tinha colocado um do gmail. e não esta indo.
O que pode ser ?
A detalhe, eu fiz outra página de contato, mas utilizando formmail, porém, fica um pouco estranho , abrir uma página diferente do meu site.

Comment: @RenanMoreira a parte que respeita esta pergunta já funciona? Isto é, enviar os dados para o PHP?

Comment: Então, eu acredito que não esteja enviando para o php, pois o php teria que enviar um email para os emails, como disse acima, mas acho que nem esteja executando o php.
Pois como disse , eu tinha utilizado ele em outro site, mas não cheguei a concluir o site totalmente, por motivos de o layout não ter me agradado. 
E mesmo quando estava em branco , ele enviava uma mensagem para os emails

Comment: E nesse site eu não tinha feito validação ou algo assim .

Comment: Vê na consola do Browser se está a enviar para o PHP. Ou coloca `echo var_dump($_REQUEST);` no PHP para confirmar.

Comment: Se estiver falando do console do F12 , la não constou nada de enviar para o php . 
tipo pelo que parece só "atualizou"

Comment: @RenanMoreira na tua página ainda tens o código errado. Não deve ser `$("#butEnviar").click(function(e) {` mas sim `$("#form").on('submit', function(e) {` como coloquei na resposta. Junta também uma classe de CSS `.incomplete{ border: 1px solid #F00; padding: 2px;}` para fazer o efeitro que tinha no jQuery.

Comment: @RenanMoreira assim: https://jsfiddle.net/zvakedvh/

Comment: Vou testar, e também estava dando uma olhada no php, e vi que estava como _REQUEST , deveria estar _POST , certo ? pelo menos nesse caso, deveria estar né ?

Comment: @RenanMoreira o jQuery faz `GET` se não tiver nada a dizer o contrário.

Comment: Então consegui arrumar pra pegar os dados, porém ,não está enviando o email ,ele está pegando os dados e tal , mas não ta postando, e também o .incomplete não esta indo, não entendi o porque '-'

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão: Use a propriedade required do html para as validações. Vai diminuir bastante esse código, aumentando a legibilidade.

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="name" />
```

É possível estilizar os inputs, utilizando pseudo classes:

```
input:required:invalid {}
input:required:valid {}
```

Fonte: [Veja Aqui](http://wbruno.com.br/html/validando-formularios-apenas-com-html5/)